# How to set bootstrap style into pager Gridview ASP.Net correctly

Tags: asp.net, gridview, twitter-bootstrap

I have a gridview and want to implement bootstrap into that gridview, I had been successfull with Header and RowItem, but failed in Pager Grid view.

**here's my code :**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridNews" runat="server"  AllowPaging="True" PageSize="2" onpageindexchanging="GridNews_PageIndexChanging"
  CssClass="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed" GridLines="None"
  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="news_id" HeaderText="ID" Visible="false" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="Date" ItemStyle-Width="50%" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderText="Title" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="LinkEvents" runat="server" Target="_blank" navigateUrl='<%# "EventsDetail.aspx?choice=investor&ev=" + Eval("news_id") %>' Text='<%# Eval("title") %>'> 
       </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
```

Is there i Missed something?

Please help me, thanks